# Why NUnit3TestAdapter doesn't work correctly for .Net 3.5 SP1?

Tags: nunit

Visual Studio 2013 Update 5, NUnit 3

I have two projects: *AcApps* and *AcApps.UnitTests*. They are compiled as *AnyCPU*. The first of them uses **.Net Framework 3.5 SP1**. Therefore I want to use the same .Net Framework version for the project with my tests (i.e. for *AcApps.UnitTests*).

I have installed `NUnit` and `NUnit3TestAdapter` in the *AcApps.UnitTests* project:

[image]

IDE shows my tests but doesn't launch them...

If I set .Net Framework 4.0 instead of .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 for *AcApps.UnitTests* project and reinstall these packages for that .Net Framework version, then IDE can launch my tests. Hm...

Why `NUnit3TestAdapter` doesn't work correctly for .Net 3.5 SP1 (in my case)? Can I fix it?

Comment: An issue has been reported with v3.4.0 of the adapter and .NET 3.5, but as of yet, can't be reproduced. I'm sure it would be a great help if you can whittle down a minimum example and help debug.
https://github.com/nunit/nunit3-vs-adapter/issues/205

Comment: I can provide both variants for the sample.